# Why does the LINQ query return no element?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have the following code, and database, and I don't understand the problem. Whenever I try to run the program, it always throws this exception:
*An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll*

In my User database there is a row with UserName: majorcsanad and Password: 722308, and when I try to log in with thus name/password, it sais it contains zero element.

My code is the following:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    szofttech2Entities context = new szofttech2Entities();
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void buttonEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var password = (from u in context.Users
                       where u.UserName == textBoxUserName.Text
                       select u.Password).Single();

        if (textBoxPassword.Text == password)
        {
            Order order = new Order();
            order.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            labelWrongUserPassword.Visible = true;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there really only one such user? `.Single` throws if more than one element satisfies a condition.

Comment: Yes, I checked it, also that column is unique.  I tried with firsOrdefault whit the same error

Comment: You are storing passwords as plain text - a big "no-no", because it makes users of your system vulnerable to taking their passwords. This should not be acceptable even as part of a learning exercise, let alone a production project.

Comment: The FirstOrDefault().  You are probably getting error due to query not finding any data.  Make sure context.Users is not null.  You may not be connecting to the database.

Comment: Put a break point on line `if (textBoxPassword.Text == password)` and see what does `password` variable holds: 1) in pop-up (hover over variable) or 2) in `Immediate Window` [Debug -> Windows -> Immediate] type in `?password` and press `Enter`.

Comment: @JohnyL It holds null.

Comment: @jdweng context.users is not null, the database has 100 entries. with the FirstOrDefault, I get the same. I am connected to the database

Comment: So, it means that no such user exists in database. Perhaps, you have case-sensitive collation or incorrect spelling. Try to get user name from table in T-SQL (in SQL Server Management Studio).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, I know, but now I am learning using c# with database, later I'll change this

Comment: Have you verified that your program is connecting to the  database you think it is? You can check by confirming that `context.Users.ToList()` actually returns the users you see in SSMS.

Comment: @hvd it shows nothing. Now, I don't understand. Maybe i misunderstand something, but in the server explorer it show a green icon at my database, also I can reach and modify my tables, so I think it is connected

Comment: i might have found the answer: when i select * from user, and export is into a csv, i get the following: majorcsanad;722308
;3
papmartin;889695;4
it is like there is a linebreak after the first password, but in the database i couldn't find it. how is this possible?

Comment: When you checked the database what did you do when you found the data? : "in my User database there is a row with UserName: majorcsanad and Password: 722308"

Comment: well, I cut it short by deleting the first row, the others works fine. I don't what cause the problem, maybe when I inserted, I mistake something. Thanks everybody for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `System.InvalidOperationException` because you're using the `.Single()` linq query.

This happens when either no elements are found or more than one is found that matches your search.  So you either have more than one user with the same username or no users with that username.

You need to also consider case when searching username.  Make sure the search either ignores case or the search changes the case of username given to the case of username in the DB.

You can also modify the code to read `SingleOrDefault()`, which will not throw an exception if not found but will still throw `System.InvalidOperationException` if more than one is found.  In your case I prefer the `Single()` because it is telling you both.  I believe the mistake is in the character case myself but that's for you to figure out.

Here's an example of sort of how I would write the code above...  You'll get the idea.

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    szofttech2Entities context = new szofttech2Entities();
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void buttonEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var password = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            password = (from u in context.Users
                        where u.UserName == textBoxUserName.Text
                        select u.Password).Single();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"None or more than one user found matching {textBoxUserName.Text}");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            if (textBoxPassword.Text == password)
            {
                Order order = new Order();
                order.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                labelWrongUserPassword.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I scratched this up on the spot just to help and I make mistakes so...